# Multiple ListView UI Virtualization

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have something like the following code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FewItems}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ManyItems}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

My problem is the second list, which is very large. Normally, UI Virtualization would take place, but since it's defined inside a scroll viewer, and a grid, the list takes as much space as it needs. This causes a significant lag when I load this page.

Settings a max height to the list doesn't do any good, since it would cause the list to scroll by itself inside the outer scroll viewer.

My questions are these:

1. Is there a way to force the list to use virtualization?
2. Is there a way to do it while keeping the scroll behavior, so both lists would scroll as a single control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualization can not work inside scroll view just as you observed. Looking at your XAML code it should be easy to solve you problem by creating intermediate collection combining FewItems and ManyItems and binding that collection to a single ListView. You could encounter some challenges if you need to style items from FewItems differently from items in ManyItems, but those can be overcome with style selectors etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did, the problem is the second list is grouped and first isn't, but I got over that. thanks.

Comment: I was having the similar problem, I have figured it out and removed scrollview and it worked. My listview is not complex like that but all items on listview are expandable. And when I go to end of the list and expand second last or any item on the screen and tries to scroll the listview, on scrolling it automatically takes me on top or mid of the listview. @Denis Do you know why its behaving like that?

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a **VirtualizingStackPanel**.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

.
.
.

**Example:**

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Border>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Wworld" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. I've actually tried something like that. The `ItemsControl` does perform virtualization, but it only performs it on the two items - the two ListViews. The second ListView still has as much space as it needs, and doesn't virtualize its items.